# How to implement menu in footer blcok

Tags: routes, blocks

I need a (D7) block print the main menu in the footer; It's not clear to me how the pieces fit together:

We implement block_info, block_view, a pre-process function and a template.

```
function MODULE_NAME_block_info() {
  $blocks['my-footer-menu'] = array(
    'info' => t('My Footer'),
  );  
  return $blocks;
}

function MODULE_NAME_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my-footer-menu'
     $tree = menu_tree_page_data('main-menu');
     $block = array( 'subject' => t('My Footer'),
                  'content' => theme('my-footer-menu', $tree),
      );
    break;
 }
return $block; 
}


function MODULE_NAME_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_footer_menu' => array(
    'template' => 'my-footer-menu',
    'variables' => array('tree' => NULL),
  ),
);
}

function template_preprocess_my_footer_menu(&$variables) {
  $variables['tree'] = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu'); 
}

<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($tree); $i++) {
    $menu = each($tree);
     if ($menu) {
        $link = array( '#theme' => 'link', 
                'title' => $menu[1]['link']['link_title'],
               'href' => $menu[1]['link']['link_path']);
          print '<a href="'  . $link['href'] . '">' . $link['title'] . '</a>';
        //  $output = theme( 'links', $link);  //this isn't right
        //  print $output;    //returns an empty string;
        }
      }
 ?>
```

The above gets the top level menu items on the page, but it's not clear how to get to the children of each menu item.   Sorry if it seems a bit muddled, just trying to cut my way through the weeds here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create all of the code yourself, but you could also use the [menu block module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) instead and save yourself a lot of work.

Comment: $menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
      print drupal_render(menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data('main-menu')));